# Double parameter from FB.event.subscribe()

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

js sdk and i have been referring about `FB.event.subsribe()`.I found a few lines of code in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe).The code is

```
var page_like_or_unlike_callback = function(url, html_element) {
  console.log("page_like_or_unlike_callback");
 console.log(url);
  console.log(html_element);
}


FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', page_like_or_unlike_callback);
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', page_like_or_unlike_callback);
```

I just need to know what url and html_element returns ..are they returning the objects ??

Hope you guys can help me in understanding this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in the docs you linked yourself:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.0#like-example

> **edge.create (string, object)**
>   A string containing the URL of the Like button target, and an object containing the element for the Like button that was clicked.